# How can i add user to a new group in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

i have created a new group which is personal to restrict some users to create new product. So i have developed a custom module to do my needs. After installing the module and adding the user to the group i connect with this user to verify if he is able to add a new product or not , and i found he can. Could any   body help me  please to verify if my code is right or not because i'm not sure if it is the right way to create a new group and add user to it

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record model="res.groups" id="your_group">
        <field name="name">Group of users who cannot create new products</field>
    </record>
</data>
```

product.py

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import fields,models,api
from openerp import tools

import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools.translate import _


 class product_product(models.Model):
_inherit = "product.product"


@api.model
def create(self, vals):
if self.env.user.has_group('yor_module.your_group'):
    raise Warning(
        _('Sorry, you are not allowed to create new products.'),
    )
else:
    return super(product_product, self).create(vals)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post your image in English language so that we can identify.

Comment: It's done , i have post an image in English language

Answer (score 0):

Your added group will not work because the user whom you don't want to give access of product creation has rights of 'Manager' in Sales. That is the highest rights. So although you have created group, it will not work.

Comment: I create this group to deny product creation for some salemanager . Do you know a solution to do that ? Any idea for help please ?

Comment: Remove manager level access from that user. Add your user to minimal access group.

Comment: Even when i choose "See Own Leads" access for sale to that user, he is always have the right to create new product